# "Monkey Business" C++ program - 99% done

Tags: c++

I'm trying to teach myself C++ using an old textbook and would appreciate your input. I can find working code for the program online, but I want to make my code work before trying completely different approaches.

I need to write a program that uses a 3x7 two-dimensional array to hold daily food consumption throughout a week by 3 monkeys.

I need to output average total daily food consumption, the least amount of weekly food consumption by any monkey, and the greatest weekly food consumption by any monkey.

Everything works so far, except for my getLeast function, which does what it sounds like - getting the least weekly food consumption among the monkeys. However, it outputs zero, while my getMost function seems to work fine.

Additionally, I welcome any comments that can offer advice on how I can improve or streamline my code. Thanks for reading!

Here's my code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

const int numROWS = 3;
const int numCOLS = 7;

void getData(int array[][numCOLS], int);
double getAverage(int array[][numCOLS], int);
int getRowSum(int array[][numCOLS], int);
double getAverage(int array[][numCOLS], int);
int getLeast(int, int, int);
int getMost(int, int, int);

int main()
{
    int monkeys[numROWS][numCOLS];
    int monkey1 = 0, monkey2 = 1, monkey3 = 2, monk1Tot, monk2Tot, monk3Tot, most, least;

    getData(monkeys,numROWS);

    monk1Tot = getRowSum(monkeys, monkey1);
    monk2Tot = getRowSum(monkeys, monkey2);
    monk3Tot = getRowSum(monkeys, monkey3);

    least = getLeast(monk1Tot, monk2Tot, monk3Tot);
    most = getMost(monk1Tot, monk2Tot, monk3Tot);

    cout << "The average daily food consumption by the monkeys was " << getAverage(monkeys, numROWS) << ". \n";
    cout << "The least amount of food consumed within the week by a single monkey was " <<least << ". \n";
    cout << "The greatest amount of food consumed within the week by a single monkey was " << most << ". \n";

}

void getData(int monkeys[][numCOLS],int numROWS)
{
    for (int rows = 0; rows < numROWS; rows++)
        {
        cout << "Monkey " << (rows + 1) << "\n";
        for (int cols = 0; cols < numCOLS; cols++)
            {
            cout << " Day " << (cols + 1) << ": ";
            cin >> monkeys[rows][cols];

            while (monkeys[rows][cols] < 0)
                {
                cout << "ERROR: Please enter a positive number: ";
                cin >> monkeys[rows][cols];
                }
            }

        cout << endl;
        }
}

int getRowSum(int monkeys[][numCOLS], int monkeyNum)
{
    int total = 0;

    for (int rows = 0; rows < monkeyNum; rows++)
    {
        for (int cols = 0; cols < numCOLS;cols++)
            total += monkeys[rows][cols];
    }

    return total;   
}

double getAverage(int monkeys[][numCOLS], int numROWS)
{
    double total = 0;

    for (int cols = 0; cols < numCOLS; cols++)
    {
        for (int rows = 0; rows < numROWS; rows++)
            total += monkeys[rows][cols];
    }

    return (total/(numCOLS));
}

int getMost(int monkey1, int monkey2, int monkey3)
{
    int array[3]{monkey1, monkey2, monkey3};
    int max = array[0];

    for (int count = 0; count < 3; count++)
    {
        if (array[count] > max)
        {
            max = array[count];
        }
    }
        return max;
}

int getLeast(int monkey1, int monkey2, int monkey3)
{
    int array[3]{monkey1, monkey2, monkey3};
    int least = array[0];

    for (int count = 0; count < 3; count++)
    {
        if (array[count] < least)
        {
            least = array[count];
        }
    }
        return least;
}
```

Comment: When you stepped through the code with a debugger, which line is causing the issue?  There is no reason for us to use a debugger for you.

Comment: 0 is probably the smallest parameter you're passing into it

Comment: I sort of prefer those global consts to be all cap letters.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in one of your functions, but it's not in `getLeast()`. Rather than telling you where it is, I'll tell you how you can find it by yourself. Start out in the function that seemingly misbehaves, namely `getLeast()`, and check if it actually receives the parameters you expect - inside the loop, use `cout` to print `array[count]`. Then, you'll see that `getLeast()` actually *returns the right answer given the parameters it received!* Figure out by hand calculation which parameters are wrong (it could be more than one). Which function is responsible for computing that/those parameters? Add some `cout` statements to that function so that it prints all the data it looks at, and you'll see that it actually includes too much or too little data in its calculation.

<sub>Hint: The error is that one of your loops is unnecessary; you repeat something for several monkeys where you were only supposed to do it for one specific monkey.</sub>